# how to add placeholder to the canvas rendering PDF Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, itext

I'm using pdf js library to render the first page of the pdf.My next plan is to show placeholder to the left side and drop in the exact postion in the canvas that HTML element needs to be added exactly at the dropped postion

But in my case element is getting added at different postions ? How to achieve the above functionalty

HTML CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PDF Renderer</title>
    <script src="./pdf.mjs" type="module"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./pdf.worker.mjs"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main-grid">
      <div class="sub-fields">
        <input type="file">
         <p draggable="true" style="cursor: pointer;">Dummy Field-Dragger</p>
      </div>
      <div class="render">
        <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
  </div>
 
 <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
var fileData;
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function () {
    let bencoded = _arrayBufferToBase64(fr.result);
    fileData = bencoded;

    renderFile(fileData);
    // console.log(atob(fr.result));
  };
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
});

document.querySelector(".render").addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.querySelector(".render").addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //get div elements
  let {offsetWidth,offsetHeight}=document.querySelector('.render');
  console.log(offsetWidth);
  console.log(offsetHeight);
  const pTag=document.createElement('p').innerText='Text Me!';
  pTag.style.left=`${offsetWidth}-${e.clientX}px`;
  pTag.style.left=`${offsetHeight}-${e.clientY}px`;
  pTag.style.position='absolute';
  pTag.style.zIndex=1000;

  document.querySelector('.render').appendChild(pTag);
  // console.log(document.querySelector)
  return false;
});

function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  var binary = "";
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return window.btoa(binary);
}

var { pdfjsLib } = globalThis;
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "./pdf.worker.mjs";
function renderFile(fileData) {
  var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: atob(fileData) });
  loadingTask.promise.then(
    function (pdf) {
      console.log("PDF loaded");
      console.log(pdf.numPages);
      // Fetch the first page
      var pageNumber = 1;
      pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        console.log("Page loaded");

        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        var canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport,
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
          console.log("Page rendered");
        });
      });
    },
    function (reason) {
      // PDF loading error
      console.error(reason);
    }
  );
}
```